# Send a greeting message when new channel created using discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
async function CreateChannel(msg,channelName){
      return await Promise.resolve(msg.guild.channels.create(channelName,{parent: 'PARENT_ID'})
      .then((msg.channel.send(`${channelName} named channel created !!`)))
      .catch(console.error));
}

function SendMessageToChannel(msg,message,channelName){

      const channel = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === channelName);
      if(!channel) return;
      channel.send(message);
}
```

I used the above two functions for a specific command to create a channel

eg: `!channel surf` creates a new channel name with surf.

What I want is when channel is created I want to automatically create a greeting message like

```
Welcome to Channel!
```

But What I'm facing not sending through code in  **SendMessageToChannel** because the **cache of the message guild is not updating**.

Help me with this!!

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for my problem**

```
async function CreateChannel(msg,channelName){
const channelCheck = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name == channelName);
if(!channelCheck){
    return await Promise.resolve(msg.guild.channels.create(channelName,{parent: '706748967790182401'})
    .then(() => {
        msg.channel.send(`${channelName} named channel created !!`);
        SendMessageToChannel(msg,`Welcome to the ${channelName}!`,channelName);
    })
    .catch(console.error));
}
else{
    msg.reply(`${channelName} already exists!`);
}
}
```

Instead of calling **SendMessageToChannel** after **CreateChannel** I called when Channel Creation promise is resolved so after the creation of channel immediate greeting/message can be send.